# How can we give the input file from storage container to azure speech api using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-speech, azure-text-translation

Below is the code,

```
call_name1="test.wav"
blob_client1=blob_service_client.get_blob_client("bucket/audio",call_name1)
print(blob_client1)

streamdownloader=blob_client1.download_blob()
stream = BytesIO()
streamfinal=streamdownloader.download_to_stream(stream)
print(streamfinal)

speech_key, service_region = "12345", "eastus"
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)

audio_input = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=streamfinal)
```

Error,

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a402ae91606a> in <module>
     44 speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
     45
---> 46 audio_input = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=streamfinal)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\speech\audio.py in __init__(self, use_default_microphone, filename, stream, device_name)
    213
    214         if filename is not None:
--> 215             self._impl = impl.AudioConfig._from_wav_file_input(filename)
    216             return
    217         if stream is not None:

TypeError: in method 'AudioConfig__from_wav_file_input', argument 1 of type 'std::string const &'
```

Please help us in reading the audio files from storage container as input in Azure speech api. Thank you!!

Comment: ```test``` isn't a string is what it's telling you.   I believe it's expecting an actual filename.    I think you should specify the ```stream``` parameter instead (judging from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.audioconfig?view=azure-python)

Comment: Inputs (audio files in .wav format) in storage containers.. We need to get it from storage container and give as input for azure speech api... Yes, audio files can't be a string right.. Can you please guide to read the audio file as stream?

Comment: @Pamela Peng, Thanks for your prompt response, but facing the same error if i pass the stream output (streamfinal=streamdownloader.download_to_stream(stream)) to the speech api (audio_input = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=streamfinal) )

Comment: Edited the code and error above @Pamela Peng

Comment: @RaphaelTitus `AudioConfig` need the stream is type `azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.AudioInputStream`. And download_to_stream  just download to stream. I'm sorry about that. I edit my reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ewong said in the comment, You need to get the `stream` instead of String.

`download_to_stream` is used to download the contents of this blob to a stream. But not `azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.AudioInputStream` what `AudioConfig` need.

I cannot find the workaround about converting stream to AudioInputStream. So, It seems only the way that downloads the audio file to the local from Storage Blob and then uploads it by AudioConfig.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

filename = "test.txt"
container_name="test-container"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=pamelastorage;AccountKey=UOyhItMnWJmB54Jmj8U0YtStNFk0vZyN1+nRem9+JwqNVJEMh5deerdfLbhVQl0ztmg96UZEUtRh2HVp8+ZJWA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net")
container_client=blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(filename)

with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    data = blob_client.download_blob()
    data.readinto(f)

audio_input = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=filename)
print(audio_input)
```

Comment: Thanks Pamela for the help.. It works fine. Appreciate!!